# Memory leak with jobjectarray parameter

Tags: java-native-interface

I have a jni method that takes in a jobjectarray of Paths as a parameter.  There is a memory leak in this code in the successful path.  I suspect that it is due to the jobject class not being released but can't figure out how to free that memory.  Here is some excerpts of the code:

```
static jclass pathClass;
static jmethodID pathMethod;

jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved) {
    JNIEnv* env;
    if ((*vm)->GetEnv(vm, (void **) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_8) != JNI_OK) {
        return JNI_ERR;
    }
    jclass localPathClass = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/nio/file/Path");
    if (localPathClass == NULL || (*env)->ExceptionOccurred(env)) {
        return JNI_ERR;
    }
    pathClass = (jclass) (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, localPathClass);
    if (pathClass == NULL || (*env)->ExceptionOccurred(env)) {
        return JNI_ERR;
    }
    pathMethod = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, pathClass, "toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
    if (pathMethod == NULL || (*env)->ExceptionOccurred(env)) {
        return JNI_ERR;
    }
}

void JNI_OnUnload(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved) {
    //printf("Unloading jni library...\n");
    JNIEnv* env;
    if ((*vm)->GetEnv(vm, (void **) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_8) != JNI_OK) {
        // Something is wrong but nothing we can do about this :(
        return;
    } else {
        if (pathClass != NULL) {
            (*env)->DeleteGlobalRef(env, pathClass);
        }
    }
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_test(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobjectArray params) {
    jsize numParams = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, params);
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < numParams; i++) {
        jobject param = (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, params, i);
        jstring jniStr = (jstring) (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, param, pathMethod);
        const char *path = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, jniStr, NULL);
        // some handling
        (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, param, path);
    }
    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, params);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you have a memory leak?  What's telling you that?

Comment: `cat /proc/<java process id>/status | grep VmRSS` - the VmRSS memory keeps growing.

Comment: You've left out `some handling`, which to me seems like the most likely culprit. By the way, there's no need for `DeleteLocalRef(env, params)`. On the other hand, depending on the length of the array, you may want to delete the references `param` and `jniStr` inside the loop at the end of each iteration.

Comment: Also, you're passing `jniStr` to `GetStringUTFChars`, but `param` to `ReleaseStringUTFChars`. That looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @Michael If I understand your comment correctly, I need to do the following: 1. I should be passing jniStr to ReleaseStringUTFChars 2. DeleteLocalRef(env, param) 3. DeleteLocalRef(env, jniStr).  What else should I be doing?

Comment: The most important change is to fix the call to `ReleaseStringUTFChars`. The `DeleteLocalRef`s inside the loop may not be necessary, but it's good practice to delete local references created inside a loop as soon as possible to avoid filling up the thread's local reference table.